# ObjectListView Treeview Get Selected tree view node Id

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I used `objectlistview` `TreeViewList` . I have a problem, i want to get the node id from my treeviewnode. i placed a `contextMenuStrip1` when user right click . i popup the the Context Menu strip. 
And i want that when user click on this Like Not Secured . i want to get the selected row value Id in this picture that is `36993` . Below is the screen of my page . 
[image]

Below is the code for my context menu open and click event .

```
  treeListView1.CellRightClick += new EventHandler<BrightIdeasSoftware.CellRightClickEventArgs>(treeListView1_CellRightClick);
  void treeListView1_CellRightClick(object sender, BrightIdeasSoftware.CellRightClickEventArgs e)
    {

        contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);

    }
```

in this line of code i want to find the selected node id that is not working

```
private void command1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // List<Node> _node = new List<Node>();
        object obj = e.GetType();
     object _node=  this.treeListView1.SelectedObjects ;
    }
```

also i try to find from this

```
private void command1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int index = data.IndexOf((Node)treeListView1.SelectedObject)
    }
```

what i am doing wrong in this code . How can i resolve it . Thanks for your comments

Comment: What exactly "not working" means? Compile-time message? Run-time exception? Not-expected result?

Comment: @Sinatr  `object _node=  this.treeListView1.SelectedObjects ;` i get nothing in `_node` from that i can find the id

Comment: Is `_node == null`? Or is it some value and you don't know how to use it? Winforms [`TreeView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx) doesn't have `SelectedObjects` property, what is `treeListView1` and what that property returns?

Comment: You confuse me with [tag:treeview]. If its [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView), then `_node` is `IEnumerable`, you have to enumerate entries in it: `foreach(var item in this.treeListView1.SelectedObjects) { ... }`. There you should be able to access items properties.. I think.

Comment: @Sinatr i am using http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html#ixzz1kSjSbSil there is objectListView

Comment: Wait, it's still `2.8`. So it's *not yet* `IEnumerable`. But what is it? You have to check documentation, because I fail to find one =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could already fetch the model object of the selected line in the `CellRightClick` handler.

```
private MyModelType _ContextModel;

void treeListView1_CellRightClick(object sender, BrightIdeasSoftware.CellRightClickEventArgs e) {
    _ContextModel = e.Model as MyModelType;
    contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
}
```

Then use `_ContextModel` in you `command1ToolStripMenuItem_Click` handler.